# Reduce a matrix to reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an exercise to find two basis to the null space of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 1 &1           \\[0.3em]
       1 & 2 & 2 &-1   \\[0.3em]
       2 & 5 & 0 &6  
     \end{bmatrix}

I'm going to use the fact that $N(A)= N(rref(A))$ ($rref(A)$ is the reduced row echelon form of A) and my basis will be:

- the pivot columns in $rref(A)$
- the corresponding columns in the original matrix $A$.

Ok, however by doing this I ended up a question:

When I get to:

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 & 1 &1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1 &-2   \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & -2 &4  
     \end{bmatrix}

Should I exchange row 2 with row 3 to have a pivot?
Also, does the operation of "exchanging rows" changes the fact that we can choose the equivalent columns in the original matrix as a basis of the null space of the matrix (tell me if I'm not being clear)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Gilbert Strang's textbook?

Comment: No, I'm watching the videos on Khan Academy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should exchange the rows in order to have a pivot.

No, exchanging rows does *not change anything about your approach*, since we are still approaching the rref of $A$. Row switching is, after all, a valid row-operation.  The only time where row-switching is problematic is if we are looking for an $LU$-decomposition (in this context, we disallow row-switches during the row-reduction process).

Note, however, that the method you describe for extracting a basis for the nullspace from the rref is incorrect; you would instead end up with a basis for the *column space*.  It is indeed sufficient, however, to determine the nullspace of $rref(A)$, which will be precisely the same as the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I confused both but now everything is clear :) Thank you very much!